Multiple Istio Mesh in single EKS cluster
We are running an Istio mesh in one single EKS cluster.
The setup looks like this:

One Istio Control Plane
One Mesh
Two Applications Namespaces (K8s)

Due to different business workload, I am thinking of creating another mesh in the same cluster.
The setup will look like this:

Two Control Planes
Two Meshes
Four Application Namespaces - 2 per Mesh

I was looking at the Isito Deployment Models https://istio.io/latest/docs/ops/deployment/deployment-models/
From the documentation, it is not clear that, whether two control planes are required for two meshes in one single cluster.
Got a hold of this document: https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/install/multiple-controlplanes/
This gave an example of two control planes for two meshes but I am not sure whether it can be implemented in production or not.
Questions:

Do I need to create two Istio control planes for two meshes in one single cluster? Is there any problems or implementation issues with this deployment pattern?
Is there any example or documentation which explains one Istio control plane with two meshes in one single cluster deployment method?
Can we deploy the above example in production? Two Istio control planes with two meshes in one single EKS cluster.

Thanks,
Suvendu

I don't really see a reason to have two different Istio control planes working separately in the same cluster, and the documentation about deployment models is not refering to this. You may have one control plane in cluster 1, being used in cluster 1,2,3...

Thanks. But is it possible to have two different meshes with one Istio control plane in Cluster 1? I have just one Cluster.

Last time I checked there were dependencies hardcoded to use istio-system namespace, maybe in latest versions is fixed. You have the flag --namespace in istioctl command to install the CP in another namespace different than istio-system.
But you may have issues with automatic sidecar injection, as it will point to istio-system webhook most likely.

You can test this: https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/install/multiple-controlplanes/. Having two control planes will help you to scope different namespaces for each one of the mesh. With this, you will have two control planes and two mesh in a single cluster
